# Proofs regarding diagonalization of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I'm trying to prove that a unitary matrix can be diagonalized using an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, and that the eigenvalues are on the unit circle. So far, I have been able to show that if A is unitary, then A is unitarily similar to T, which is unitary and upper-triangular. Basically, I need to show that T is diagonal, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Additionally, I want to prove that a matrix is positive definite iff it can be diagonalized using an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, and that the eigenvalues are real and positive. I've already written a similar proof for Hermitian matrices, with the eigenvalues real (but not necessarily positive). However, I'm having trouble seeing where to start with this one.

Comment: All this is on any linear algebra book. That's probably the fastest way for you to learn this stuff.

Comment: If T is upper triangular and symmetric then it is diagonal.

Comment: That's what I have been trying, but the book I have is really not very helpful. It describes each individual concept very well, but it doesn't help me to understand how they tie together.

Comment: mtiano, how do I know that T is symmetric though? All I know is that it's upper triangular and unitary.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, partition $T$ as $\pmatrix{a& b^\ast\\ 0&C}$, where $a$ is a scalar. Then $I=TT^\ast=\pmatrix{|a|^2+\|b\|^2& b^\ast C^\ast\\ Cb&CC^\ast}$. It follows that $C$ is unitary, $b=0$ and $|a|=1$. Yet $C$ is upper triangular. Therefore, by mathematical induction, $C$ is diagonal. Hence $T$ is diagonal.

For your second question, note that every positive definite matrix is, by definition, Hermitian.

Comment: That helps a lot with the first one. However with the second, I can see that a positive definite matrix is Hermitian, but I'm still having trouble understanding how to prove both sides of the theorem.

Comment: @AaronJasa If $A$ can be diagonalised using an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, and all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive, then $A=UDU^\ast$ for some unitary matrix $U$, and $D$ is a positive diagonal matrix. So you can show that $A$ is positive definite by showing that $x^\ast Ax\ge0$ for every vector $x$.

Comment: How would I show that though? And what about the other direction? I really can't stress enough how confusing linear algebra is to me.